# OData Binding expand parameters one to many relationship

Tags: odata, sapui5

Read multiple question here regarding this problem, but none of them helped.

I have the following table:

```xml
<Table id="table"
  width="auto"
  items="{
    path: '/Master',
    sorter: {
      path: 'id',
      descending: false
    },
    parameters: {
      expand: 'ToB'
    }
  }"
>
```

How can I display properties from `ToB` in my table?
Because `ToB` has a *one to many* relationship with `Master`, this isn't working (I guess that's the reason):

```xml
    <cells>
      <Text text="{ToB/name1}" />
    </cells>
```

whereas this works:

```xml
    <cells>
      <VBox items="{ToB}">
        <Text text="{name1}"/>
      </VBox>
    </cells>
```

`ToB` has a property "selected" which can be `0` or `1`. Only one of the entries to an ID in the `Master` table can be `1`, so I thought that is a way to get my `1` to `1` relationship.
But I can't work out, how to do this, already tried it with expression binding:

```xml
<Text text="{= ${ToB/selected} === 1 ? ${ToB/name1} : 'No Entry'}"/>
```

but it always displays "No Entry" in my table.

**Edit:** for testing purposes it tried:

```xml
<Text text="{= ${ToB/selected} === 1 ? ${ToB/name1} : ${ToB/name1}}"/>
```

but it just leaves the column of my table empty, so I'm guessing the binding isn't correct.

**Edit 2:** to clarify my question, I got it working using VBox, but I want to have 1 entry per row i.e. there are the names Peter, Paul, and Mary for the specific ID, only Peter has the "selected" value `1`, so I want just Peter in this table row.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

The reason why `text="{ToB/name1}"` doesn't work is because resolving the path `ToB` returns a **collection** due to the "many"-cardinality which doesn't work for *property binding*.

This means also, on the other hand, that it works for *aggregation binding* as you could observe already with `<VBox items="{ToB}"/>`.

### Alternative

> I want to have 1 entry per row i.e. there are the names Peter, Paul, and Mary for the specific ID, only Peter has the "selected" value 1, so I want just Peter in this table row.

If you'd like to display only a certain entity from `ToB` in `<VBox>`, you could define a filter respectively in the view directly. In your case, by `"selected" === 1`.

```xml
<Table items="{
  path: '/Master',
  parameters: {
    expand: 'ToB'
  }
}">
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <VBox items="{
        path: 'ToB',
        filters: [
          {
            path: 'selected',
            operator: 'EQ',
            value1: 1
          }
        ]
      }">
        <Text text="{name1}"/>
      </VBox>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
  <!-- ... -->
</Table>
```